# Отследить изменение объекта, промисы

Tags: node.js, promise

у меня такой код:

```
var db=require("../api/mongo")
module.exports=function(id,error) {
    return new Promise((r,e)=>{
        db().collection("users").findOne({ vk:id },function(err,user){
            r(user);
         })
    })
}
```

Если подключить этот модуль, то с помощью `require("module-name")(id)` мы можем получить объект пользователя и работать с ним через промис.

```
 require("module-name")(123).then(user=>{
      //работаем с объектом user    
 })
```

Вопрос в том, как модуль сможет узнать обновленный объект `user`? Что бы сохранить в mongodb. Передача в коллбэк не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [прокси](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```
const db = require('../api/mongo');

module.exports = (id, error) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        db().collection('users').findOne({
            vk: id
        }, (error, user) => {
            resolve(new Proxy(user, {
                set(_, key, value) {
                    db().collection('users').updateOne({
                        vk: id
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            [key]: value
                        }
                    });

                    return Reflect.set(...arguments);
                }
            }));
        });
    });
};
```